# JavaCC Lexer Generator Integration the NetBeans Platform

Tags: java, netbeans, editor, lexer, javacc

I am new in using JavaCC. I was trying to integrate editor for our company defined  language. I need to change keywords and modify the syntax. I follow [this link](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-javacc-lexer.html#generating)
as a procedure. For testing i change the some lines below from the code link.
I change keyword *finally*  with *require*. I change following lines in code.

**JavaParserConstants.java**

```
    int FALSE = 25;
    /** RegularExpression Id. */
    int FINAL = 26;
    /** RegularExpression Id. */
    //int FINALLY = 27;
    int REQUIRE=27;
    /** RegularExpression Id. */
    int FLOAT = 28;
    /** RegularExpression Id. */

         *
         *
    String[] tokenImage = {
         *
    "\"false\"",
    "\"final\"",
    "\"require\"",//fınally
    "\"float\"",
```

**SJLanguageHierarchy.java**

```
 private static void init() {
  tokens = Arrays.<SJTokenId>asList(new SJTokenId[]{
         *
         *
   new SJTokenId("FALSE", "keyword", 25),
   new SJTokenId("FINAL", "keyword", 26),
   new SJTokenId("REQUIRE"/*"FINALLY"*/, "keyword", 27), 
   new SJTokenId("FLOAT", "keyword", 28)
```

**Java1.5.jj**

```
/* RESERVED WORDS AND LITERALS */
TOKEN :
{
*
*
| < FALSE: "false" >
| < FINAL: "final" >
| < REQUIRE: "require" >
| < FLOAT: "float" >
```

But it did not affect still when i am using new integrated "editor" it highlight the old syntax including keyword *finally*.Any suggestions or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you modify the generated JavaParserConstants.java file?

Comment: I want to change the syntax according my company language.

Comment: But this is a generated file and will only be overwritten the next time you run javacc.  See FAQ 2.2 in http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/ .  Also, since you modified the Java1.5.jj file, the change you made to the JavaParserConstants.java should not be needed. So next question: After you modified the .jj file, did you run JavaCC to regenerate the .java files?

Comment: Nice catch probably that is what my mistake is !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Theodore Norvell I find out that my code does not work if i change my keywords after generating code. The Java1.5.jj file should be first changed and then generated it was keypoint that i stacked.